# how to store and display multiline text in firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

when i store data using

```
  <vs-textarea  v-model="textarea" label=" Description "  rows="5"  />
```

e.g.

```
       abc
       def
       geh
```

the data is stored in the firestore in the format of string

`abc def geh`

and same is displayed when retrieved
using

```
 <vs-collapse>
                <vs-collapse-item>
                    <div slot="header">Read More</div>  
                   {{ jobDetails.description }}

                    </vs-collapse-item>
            </vs-collapse>
```

how can i store multiline text in firestore ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add '\n' characters as newline characters and use `white-space: pre-wrap` css to display them.
https://codepen.io/GuillaumeMeral/pen/NWWNWMr

Answer (score 1):

Just format the text with your own delimiter and then split it back. Example:

> The quick brown fox^jumps over the lazy dog

Here I use the `^` character as delimiter. Now just use a split like:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^");
String[] result = pattern.split(INPUT_STRING);
```